# Add custom field to Hibernate Envers revision table (revinfo), like operation_id. Which is a PK of Operation entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, audit, hibernate-envers

Hi i was wondering if it is possible to add a custom field like Operation_id to revinfo table, which will have custom operations, like ADD_TRAVEL_OP. These operations should be set in each endpoint statically or dynamically.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "revinfo")
@RevisionEntity(AuditRevisionListener.class)
public class AuditRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "rev")
    private int revision;

    private String username;

    private String operationId;

    public int getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(final int revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(final String userName) {
        this.username = userName;
    }

    public String getOperationId() {
        return operationId;
    }

    public void setOperationId(final String operationId) {
        this.operationId = operationId;
    }
```

```java
@Configuration
public class AuditRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        final AuditRevisionEntity are = (AuditRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication instanceof UserDetails) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            are.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
        } else {
            are.setUsername(authentication.getName());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can add fields to your AuditRevisionEntity. The trick is you have to have access to data from within the AuditRevisionListener. I had a requirement that some operations needed to record a reason for change in the audit trail (AuditRevisionEntity). I ended up using a thread local to store the reason for change, setting the reason for change in the AuditRevisionListener using the thread local, and clearing the thread local when a transaction starts or when it completes.

The JpaTransactionManager implementation:

```
public class AuditingJpaTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {
  private final AuditContextHolder auditContextHolder = new AuditContextHolder();
  
  public AuditingJpaTransactionManager() {
    super();
  }

  public AuditingJpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    super(emf);
  }
  
  @Override
  protected void doBegin(Object transaction, TransactionDefinition definition) {
    this.auditContextHolder.clearContext();
    super.doBegin(transaction, definition);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doCleanupAfterCompletion(Object transaction) {
    this.auditContextHolder.clearContext();
    super.doCleanupAfterCompletion(transaction);
  }
}
```

The thread local implementation:

```
public class AuditContextHolder {
  private static final ThreadLocal<AuditContext> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();
  
  public void clearContext() {
    contextHolder.remove();
  }
  
  public AuditContext getContext() {
    AuditContext ctx = contextHolder.get();
    
    if (ctx == null) {
      ctx = new AuditContext();
      contextHolder.set(ctx);
    }
    
    return ctx;
  }
  
  @NoArgsConstructor
  public static class AuditContext {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String reasonForChange;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of Lee Greiner, i achieved my goal. i will leave here the rest, which is obvious, but nonetheless can help others.

```java
//update to what i already had
public class AuditRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {

        final AuditRevisionEntity are = (AuditRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication instanceof UserDetails) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            are.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
        } else {
            are.setUsername(authentication.getName());
        }
        String operationId = new AuditContextHolder().getContext().getOperationId();
        if(operationId == null) operationId = Operation.NOT_DEFINED.name();
        are.setOperationId(operationId);
    }

}
```

```java
//Set the desired Operation before the save point
new AuditContextHolder()
.getContext()
.setOperationId(Operation.LOGIN_OP.name());
```